# Cuándo usar un struct en C++

Tags: c++

A partir de un enunciado:

> ¿cuándo puedo saber si necesito un **struct**?

Comment: Un struct se usa para crear estructuras de datos. ¿Cuando lo necesitas? Pues cuando tengas que agrupar datos con un sentido común ... por ejemplo, los datos de un usuario, o si vas a gestionar la información de una serie de coches... pero claro, usar un `struct` no va a ser algo obligatorio sino, normalmente, conveniente, ya que permite organizar y agrupar la información de una forma coherente

Answer (score 6):

Normalmente lo utilizamos `struct` para organizar información, es decir; es una agrupación de datos bajo un mismo nombre.
Un ejemplo lo podemos representar cuando realizamos un nodo:

```
struct Nodo{
   int dato;  
   Nodo*siguiente;  
};
```

Nosotros estamos agrupando en un mismo nombre (Node) un dato de tipo entero con un puntero que apunta al siguiente.
Otro ejemplo podría ser el siguiente:

```
 struct Album{
    string nombreDelAlbum;
    string nombreDeLaCancion;
    int numeroDeLaPista;
    float duracion;
 };
```

Agrupamos de la estructura `album`una serie de datos en las cuales son de sentido común.

Answer (score 1):

Definimos Struct a la estructura de datos formada por un conjunto de elementos (no necesariamente de igual tipo). Los utilizamos mayormente cuando se requiere organizar múltiples datos de la misma entidad en una única estructura. Un ejemplo seria usarlo para la ficha de un alumno:

```
struct ficha {
  string apellido;
  string nombres;
  long dni;
  int edad;
  int cant_materias;
};
```